# Let ${X_n}$ with parameter $\lambda$ be a Poisson variable, show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{n}^{2} \rightarrow \lambda + \lambda^2$ q.c

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I can't see how it goes to $\lambda$.

Let ${X}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ independent Poisson with parameter $\lambda$ be a Poisson variable, show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}^{2} \rightarrow \lambda + \lambda^2$ q.c

Comment: Immediate from Strong Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2$ I guess. $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_n^2$ makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you @geetha290krm. I got it now. I hadn't gotten to the chapter on this topic yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be really off, and in case please someone correct me, but I'm inclined to think that the result is wrong.

I'd say that $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_k X_{k}^{2} \to \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] = \lambda + \lambda^2$$

Comment: You are right. I corrected the statment. Thank you.